# calling jquery function in php after form post, the notification doesnt show

Tags: php, jquery

```
$result=$db->add_tender($t_name,$t_code,$t_category,$discription,$s_funds,$price,$deadline,$apply_to,$contact,$t_status,$_SESSION["VALID_USER_IDENTITY"]);

     if($result==false){

         $Err="Some thing went Wrong!-->".$result;
     }
     else{

         $last_id=$result;
        $message="Tender Successfully Added!";

   ?>
 <script type="text/javascript">
                    function showAutoCloseMessage(){
                        showNotification({
                            message: ""<?php echo $message; ?>",
                            autoClose: true,
                            duration: 2
                        });    
                    }                                
                </script>
   <?php
    //header('Location:v_tender.php?t_id='.$last_id);

    //header('Location:view_tenders.php');

     }
```

Comment: Code color should have identified this line `message: ""<?php echo $message; ?>",` remove the double double quote in here

Comment: I think you didn't call to showAutoCloseMessage function. Just declare?

Comment: thanx for replying i removed the double quote and doesnt work

Comment: @Quỳnh Nguyễn, you mean i need to call afte  the function declaration like:- echo 'showAutoCloseMessage()';

Comment: @japharyjuma Yes bro.

Answer (score 0):

Replace belo code

```
showNotification({
     message: ""<?php echo $message; ?>",
     autoClose: true,
     duration: 2
});
```

By

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    showNotification({
         message: "<?php echo $message; ?>",
         autoClose: true,
         duration: 2
    });   
});
```

because "" is treated as string is closed but string not closed there. also it gives error in console.

Comment: if its not working please check position of call function showAutoCloseMessage(); it muxt be called after document is ready.